# laravel mysql how to search a string to see if a value is present

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause

I'm using mysql to store a number of projects.
In the mysql database each projects has a column called 'keywords' that is a string.
the data looks like this...
react, nodejs, mysql, html

I want to search for a string (ie php, react, mysql, etc) to see if it is contained within each rows 'keywords' column.
I've tried using where and where in but I can't get it to work.
I can get where to work if there is only one value in the keywords.

an example from my controller

```
    public function php()
    {
        $projects = Projects::where('keywords','like',"php")->get();
        // dump($projects);
        return view('projects.php', ['projects' => $projects]);
    }
```

An example of how I used whereIn

```
    public function react()
    {
        $projects = Projects::whereIn('keywords','react')->get();
        return view('projects.react', ['projects' => $projects]);
    }
```

When I use where or whereIn with more than one keyword I get a empty array. When I use where with just one keyword (as in, I deleted all of the keywords in the string column except one) it works perfectly.

But I want to have multiple keywords in each column as each project will be used in multiple pages.

Thanks again everyone! Stack overflow is the bomb!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-Column has multiple keywords**

If you put together all keywords in one column you should use like with %

```
$projects = Projects::where('keywords','like',"%php%")->get();
```

If you want search multiple keywords in one time:

```
$projects = Projects::where('keywords','like',"%php%")
->orWhere('keywords','like',"%react%")->get();
```

**2-Column has one keyword**

If you want to search one keyword in column you can use

```
$projects = Projects::where('keywords',"php")->get();
```

If you want to search multiple keywords in column you can use

```
$projects = Projects::whereIn('keywords',['php','react'])->get();
```